# Why will my jQuery not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to find an error in my HTML, jquery, or even CSS which is preventing my jQuery from even loading, to no avail. Any help is appreciated

#### Code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';
  $("#IndexContent").hide();
  $("#BidListMainMenu").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).slideToggle();
  });
  $("Table").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
  <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
  <title>Main Menu</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<div id="IndexBackgroundImage"></div>

<body id="Index">
  <div id="IndexLogoDiv">
    <img src="images/logo.gif" alt="Logo" />
  </div>

  <center>

    <div id="IndexContent">

      <h1>Intranet</h1>

      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="mainButton">
              <img alt="Bid List" src="images/IndexBidList.png" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <div id="BidListMainMenu">
            <td>
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="1">
                      <a href="BidList/CurrentBid.php">
                        <img alt="Bid List alteration" src="images/BidList.png" />
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="1">
                      <a href="Bidlist/NewProject.php">
                        <img alt="Add New Project" src="images/AddNewProject.png" />
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="1">
                      <a href="BidList/EditProject.php">
                        <img alt="Edit Project" src="images/EditProject.png" />
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="1">
                      <a href="BidList/Priorities.php">
                        <img alt="Priorities" src="images/SetPriorities.png" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="1">
                      <a href="BidList/Maintenence.php">
                        <img alt="Edit Project" src="images/Maintenence.png" />
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </div>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img alt="Bid List alteration" src="images/IndexMaintenence.png" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="">
                <img alt="Wordpress Page" src="images/IndexWordpress.png" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="IndexFooterDiv">
      <img src="images/address.gif" alt="Address" />
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

There is no evidence of the jQuery even starting, which is unusual, because it is linked, and I imported the library. I can post the css if it is helpful. I put the first `$("#IndexContent").hide()` test case there to check if it loaded. However nothing worked. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Use `document` with lowercase `d`

Answer (score 4):

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

should be:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sometimes it's 'better' to use `//` instead of explicitly specifying the protocol. That way, it assumes whatever protocol the page is being accessed on.

Answer (score 3):

You have a wrong src attribute for `cdn` source:

```
src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"
```

which should be:

```
src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"  // will look https || http
```

and you have a typo for the :

```
$(Document).ready // you can see the uppercase D in the document
```

Answer (score 1):

first, I would change the html `<script src = >`to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

After, you typed

```
$(Document).ready(function () {});
```

Change that `Document` to `document`

Comment: oops, sorry, didn't see it. I'll be more careful next time